# Jest Manual Mock Not Working with Manual Implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am testing some of my code using Jest. When I try to mock a function (autogenerated by pgtyped), the test fails, saying the function returns `undefined`. My original function is in: `src/db/models/calls.ts`, and my mocked function is in `src/db/models/__mocks__/calls.ts`.

To try to better understand the issue I am facing, I am trying to get the mocked function to simply `console.log` the parameters it receives. Below is the mocked function:

```
export const getCallBySid = {
    run: jest.fn().mockImplementation((params: { sid: string }) => {
        console.log("getCallBySid params", params);
    }),
};
```

What makes this even more confusing is, when I replace `jest.fn().mockImplementation` with a direct implementation in the mock file, the console.log works. Below is the code that is able to console.log

```
export const getCallBySid = {
    run: (params: { sid: string }) => {
        console.log("getCallBySid", params);
    },
};
```

I can't tell why this would work, whereas the jest mock would not. I want to be able to get information on calls to the function, so it would be very helpful to be able to have it be a jest.fn in the mock.